# How to apply discount on shipping for a special product on woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

is there any way discount on shipping for a special product?

All USA shipping cost is $10.00 but if a product is in a cart the shipping cost will be $3.00 I have tried this using coupon code. How Can I check Billing /Shipping Country ?

But it set discount on total cost but I need to discount the shipping I also use different shipping classes.

What I am trying.

```
function shipping_costs_discounted( $rates, $package ){
 if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return $rates;

foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product_id_in_cart = array( 1391193 );// this is product ID
        if( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $product_id_in_cart ) ) {   

            //Looking for the shipping classes
            $shipping_class = 'special-offer-discount'; // <=== Shipping class slug
            $discount_rate  = 1.46;
            $is_found       = false;
            // Loop through cart items and checking for the specific defined shipping class
            foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ) {
                if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class() == $shipping_class )
                    $is_found = true;
            }
            // Set shipping costs shipping class is found
            if( $is_found ){
                foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
                    $has_taxes = false;
                    // Targeting "flat rate"
                    if( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id  ){
                        $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rate->cost - $discount_rate;

                        // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
                        foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                            if( $tax > 0 ){
                                $has_taxes = true;
                                $taxes[$key] = $tax - $discount_rate;
                            }
                        }
                        if( $has_taxes )
                            $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
                    }
                }
            }
            return $rates;
        }
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_costs_discounted', 10, 2);
```

Comment: your  goal and the code you tried are in different direction, and why would you want to get the billing/shipping Country?

Comment: because I want to apply it for only US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you'll modify the `woocommerce_package_rates` filter, all the items in cart are in `$package` variables inside `contents` key, so you can simply loop through it and pull all the id for checking if the product you want are in there.

Destination info are also in the `$package` variable inside `destination` keys, it contains full shipping address including country;

this is an example json output of `$package` variable

```
{
    "contents": {
        "044a23cadb567653eb51d4eb40acaa88": {
            "key": "044a23cadb567653eb51d4eb40acaa88",
            "product_id": 2754,
            "variation_id": 0,
            "variation": [],
            "quantity": 2,
            "data_hash": "b5c1d5ca8bae6d4896cf1807cdf763f0",
            "line_tax_data": {
                "subtotal": [],
                "total": []
            },
            "line_subtotal": 35.9,
            "line_subtotal_tax": 0,
            "line_total": 35.9,
            "line_tax": 0,
            "data": {}
        },
        "0fc170ecbb8ff1afb2c6de48ea5343e7": {
            "key": "0fc170ecbb8ff1afb2c6de48ea5343e7",
            "product_id": 2800,
            "variation_id": 0,
            "variation": [],
            "quantity": 1,
            "data_hash": "b5c1d5ca8bae6d4896cf1807cdf763f0",
            "line_tax_data": {
                "subtotal": [],
                "total": []
            },
            "line_subtotal": 107.95,
            "line_subtotal_tax": 0,
            "line_total": 107.95,
            "line_tax": 0,
            "data": {}
        }
    },
    "contents_cost": 143.85,
    "applied_coupons": [],
    "user": {
        "ID": 1
    },
    "destination": {
        "country": "US",
        "state": "",
        "postcode": "",
        "city": "Pine Bluff",
        "address": "",
        "address_1": "",
        "address_2": ""
    },
    "cart_subtotal": 143.85,
    "rates": {
        "flat_rate:3": {}
    }
}
```

So with that info, you can do something like this to modify the Shipping Cost and Shipping label

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', '_shipping_cost_product_ID', 100, 2);
function _shipping_cost_product_ID( $rates, $package ){

    // duh
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return $rates;

    // The ID of the product you want to modify shipping cost if found in cart
    $discounted_product_id = 2800;

    // Get all the product IDs added in cart and put them in array
    $ids_in_cart = [];
    foreach ( $package['contents'] as $key => $item ) {
        $ids_in_cart[] = $item['product_id'];
    }

    // loop through each shipping rates
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){

        $has_taxes = false;

        // Only modify shipping if all conditions below are meet
        if( 
            'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id // if shipping method is "Flat RATE"
            && ( isset($package['destination']['country'] ) && $package['destination']['country'] == 'US' )  // if country is US
            && in_array($discounted_product_id, $ids_in_cart )//if $discounted_product_id is in cart
            ) {

            $rates[$rate_key]->label = 'Cool Shipping'; // Modify Shipping Name
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 3.00; // Modify Shiping Cost

            //Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            $taxes = [];
            foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key] > 0 ){
                    $initial_tax_cost = $new_tax_cost = $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key];
                    $tax_rate    = $initial_tax_cost / $initial_cost;
                    $taxes[$key] = $new_cost * $tax_rate;
                    $has_taxes   = true; 
                }
            }
            if( $has_taxes ) $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man you solve my issue and it works like charm :)

Comment: Anyway to use this to only discount the shipping rate for 1 specific product in the cart NOT the total shipping costs?